# If statement in grouped dataframe and date comparision

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains columns of countries `GEOGN` and their historic data. I have grouped the data by countries and eliminated all rows where `df` is lower than the 5% quantile for each country with `NaN`. The code is below:

```
def replace(group):
    quantile = group.quantile(0.05)
    smallest_five = group < quantile
    group[smallest_five ] = np.NaN
    return group

df = df.groupby('GEOGN').apply(replace)
```

Consider the following dataframe:

```
  GEOGN  2009-06  2010-01  2010-02   ...     2011-02  2011-03  2011-04  2011-05
0   GER        1        4       10   ...           4        7        6        3
1   GER        5        6        9   ...           6        2       10        2
2   GER        1        4        7   ...           4        8        6        6
3   GER       10        9        6   ...           6        2        1        8
4   USA        9        9        5   ...          10        3        1       10
5   USA        2        4        5   ...           4        5        4        3
6   USA        3        4        3   ...           8        4        2        1
7   USA       10        2        8   ...           2        3        9        9
```

Now I would like to perform the same operation based on a condition.

First, the operation should check whether `month < 6` or `month > 5` is true in each column. If the first statement is true, then it should perform a slightly different operation as above. It should compare the `df` with the previous 5% quantile: `outliers = group < quantile.shift(1)`.

Here's a rough idea of my current approach:

```
def replace(group):
    quantile = group.quantile(0.05)
    smallest_five = group < quantile.shift(1)
    group[smallest_five] = np.NaN
    return group

 def replace_next(group):
    quantile = group.quantile(0.05)
    smallest_five = group < quantile
    group[smallest_five] = np.NaN
    return group

for column_name in df.drop(df.columns[range(1)], axis=1):
    column_date = pd.to_datetime(column_name)
    if column_date.month < 6:
         df.groupby('GEOGN').apply(replace)
    else:
         df.groupby('GEOGN').apply(replace_next)
```

Appreciate any suggestions.